# Could not find or load main class Testing

Tags: java, selenium

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Testing

My `Testing.java` code does contain a `main` method (below), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class  Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxProfile profile = null;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe")), profile);
        //FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the code did compile and you are not executing an old version of it?

Comment: See "Related", to the right.

Comment: Yes code is compile.